Help formulating objection to Parfit's personal identity and response to objection
I am working on a Metaphysics paper defending Parfit's psychological continuity and connectedness criterion for survival and need help formulating an objection, responding to the objection, and advice on whether or not it is completely misguided and how it can be reformulated if so. The rough idea behind the objection is as follows. An individual A pre-fission holds the intentions, wishes, and desires to not survive the operation. According to Parfit, A would survive the operation as both resulting individuals through psychological continuity and connectedness. Psychological connectedness is to be viewed as "A being psychologically connected, at some future time, with you as you are now just if she is in the psychological states she is in then in large part because of the psychological states you are in now." The conclusion would then emphasize the tension (I want to posit the "impossibility" but am not quite sure how to convey this) between "being in a psychological state in large part because of the psychological states you are in now" with the fact that the resulting post fission individuals B and C are manifestations of the exact opposite of A's wishes, desires, and intentions. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I don't quite understand why or how A not wishing to survive is an objection to Parfit's idea of continuity. If A does not wish to survive then Parfit's teleporting (or simply continuing one's life) doesn't seem a good way to ensure that. But how is that an objection to Parfit's ideas? An opponent of Parfit would be doubly sad, since apparently they survived, which would apparently prove Parfit to be right...

I mean, how are the post-fission individuals in any relevantly other state than A? Presumably they would be in the same state, as far as fission is concerned, namely that don't want to survive any future fission. And if "fission" here simply means the process of living, then A, B, C are all in a painful apparently suicidal state - but that is by itself no objection to Parfit's ideas. Am I misreading your question?

Could you describe Parfit's objective, what he wants to prove, and his thought experiment? It would be helpful for clarity to do that in separate paragraphs.

Parfit's psychological continuity and survival doesn't require perfect replication of A's pre-fission mental states in B and C as strict personal identity. It only requires that B's and C's psychological states be causally connected to A's pre-fission psychological states. Thus B and C might recognize A's pre-fission desire not to survive but come to different conclusions based on the broader psychological context post-fission. The tension you describe may feel ethically significant, but it does not undermine the descriptive continuity that defines survival in Parfit's terms.

So to strengthen your objection to construct a metaphysical barrier to survival instead of a mere moral dilemma, argue that Parfit's account fails to respect the normative aboutness mark of psychological states. Psychological continuity may be insufficient for survival if they fail to honor the first-person perspective and intentions of the pre-fission individual. Survival may require more than descriptive connectedness to avoid contravention of agency which is normative in nature. Additionally Parfit is overly reductive physicalistic here, what if some emergent states break continuity?...

Mudskipper has given a good critique of your attempted objection. I don't think bringing intentions into the mix will help here.

As an alternative, think about attacking some of the foundational assumptions Parfit made. If "all that matters" is psychological continuity and connectedness, then can you derive a strongly counterintuitive result from this or show it conflicts with some other strongly held principle?
I think the main objection people have to Parfit's view is the loss of identity. His criteria only relates to survival, but they sacrifice identity in the process. Imagine that the operation results in two people who act nothing like A due to the damage done to the brain. Or, more pointedly, if one of the two will be horribly tortured, I think that would be of prudential concern to me pre-op ;-). Subjectivity is experienced as a singular point of view by necessity, so to me it isn't just continuity and connectedness that matters but also which one "I" will end up being.
Now, I am a big fan of Parfit, and I actually agree with his views so the above is just an example of a though that I had while coming to grips with his ideas.
Hope this helps.
